# How to validate "### ##" number format in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I need to be abble to validate user input in VB, where the user writes 5 numbers like this "### ##", 3 numbers, a gap and 2 more numbers. How do I do this the best way?

Thanks, Mike.

Comment: You're looking for regular expressions. You should probably be more specific about the version of VB you're using so we can give you more specific answers.

Comment: 2010 is the version of the visual studio - we just need to know vb.net vs vb6 vs vba vs vbscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression? `"\d{3}\s\d{3}"`

For example, using a RegularExpressionAttribute

```
Public Class Model
     <RegularExpression( "^\d{3}\s\d{3}$", ErrorMessage:="You must enter the date as ### ##" )>_
     Public Property Data as String
        'Getter and setter logic
     End Property
End Class
```

using the Regex class

```
...
Public Function Validate( ByVal data as String ) as Boolean
     Static ValidationRegex as Regex = new Regex("^\d{3}\s\d{3}$",RegexOptions.Compiled) 

     Validate = ValidationRegex.IsMatch( data )
End Function
```

I think it's possible in VB6, but don't have an example for you.

Comment: Thank you, how exactly can I use it in a condition?

Comment: @Mike I'd need more information on what you are validating, the validation context, the version of VB you are using.  If you're talking about VB with MVC, you can just use a RegularExpressionAttribute on your model, for example. If you're doing it in code, you might be able to use the System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex class if you're using VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Let your code format the string automatically. This makes it easier for the users

```
Dim s As String
Dim n As Integer

s = textBox1.Text.Replace(" ","")  ' Remove spaces
If s.Length = 5 AndAlso Int32.TryGetValue(s, n) Then
    textBox1.Text = n.ToString("000 00")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("You must enter five digits!")
EndIf
```

Comment: Even better: remove anything that's not a digit before checking for the length, rather than just spaces.

Comment: Yes, that would be something like `Regex.Replace(s,"[^0-9]","")` or `Regex.Replace(s,"\D","")`

Answer (score 1):

Might be overly simplifying it but I'd just use a masked input box.

Answer (score 1):

That would be perfect for the [`Like`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) operator:

```
If "123 45" Like "### ##" Then
```